# Build chromium for release/sharing

Tags: google-chrome, browser, compilation, chromium, ninja

What arguments can I use to build chromium in a separate folder from the gen folder.

I don't want all the copied

> api-ms-win-core

dlls to be packed with the release.

Along with the exp, lib, and ilk files that are generated for compiling.

I just need the bare files that chromium needs to run on another PC.

Answer (score 1):

In the build directory try `ninja installer` or `ninja mini_installer`. It should create another artefact, a single .exe installer.